# select change event

Tags: jquery

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#issue_no').change(function()
{
   alert('Value change to ' + $(this).attr('value'));
});

});
```

HTML

```
<select id='issue_no' name='issue_non'>
    <option value='_empty' selected='selected' style='display:none;'></option>
    <option value="ABC">Vol 1, No 1 (2012): Journal of JISRComputing</option>
</select>
```

Doesnt seem to work. Why?
why is alert not being displayed when changing the select value.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Does it not alert anything, or does it alert the wrong value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're referencing jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

Wrap your code in a ready function:

```
$(function(){
  /* Code Here */
});
```

Be sure to check your `id`'s and markup for correct structure:

```
<select id='issue_no' name='issue_non'>
    <option value='_empty' selected='selected' style='display:none;'></option>
    <option value="ABC">Vol 1, No 1 (2012): Journal of JISRComputing</option>
</select>
```

Write well-formatted JavaScript for ease of readability:

```
$(function(){
    $("#issue_no").on("change", function(){
        alert( this.value );
    });
});
```

After all of this, it works: http://jsbin.com/obadub/edit#javascript,html

As always, make sure you don't have problems elsewhere on your page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Alert Selected Value</title>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#issue_no").on("change", function(){
        alert( this.value );
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id='issue_no' name='issue_non'>
      <option value='_empty' selected='selected' style='display:none;'></option>
      <option value="ABC">Vol 1, No 1 (2012): Journal of JISRComputing</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont know what the problem was but following your post, I managed to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

[It works](http://jsfiddle.net/zaeFM/). Your problem probably lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to use `$(document).ready(function() {...});` (or its shorthand form `$(function() {...});`), or simply move that script to the bottom of the page, right before the closing body tag (`</body>`).

Also, there are a whole number of better alternatives for getting the value out, rather than using `.attr('value')` (which I'm not convinced is even going to work as you want). Calling the `.val()` jQuery function (`$(this).val()`) or simply accessing the property directly, using `this.value`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like

```
$(function() {
   $('#issue_no').on("change", function()
   {
      alert('Value change to ' + $(this).val());
   });
});
```

Comment: You can, *if you're using jQuery 1.7+*, though they're functionally equivalent (`.change()` will call `.on()` in the jQuery code when passed a function).

Comment: I don't see the problem to use the latest version of jquery...It's better because will solve many issues and use new functions

Comment: Personally, I can't guarantee that nothing is going to break if I update to the latest version, and I don't have the time to go back and retest (and then potentially fix) that amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#issue_no').on('change', function () {
                alert('Value change to ' + $(this).attr('value'));
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id='issue_no' name='issue_non'>
        <option value='_empty' selected='selected' style='display: none;'></option>
        <option value="ABC">Vol 1, No 1 (2012): Journal of JISRComputing</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if u r appending drop down list. then u need to use 'on'.

Comment: If you're dynamically appending the element then your code isn't going to work, that's a standard event binding to an element that's assumed to exist when the code is run, **not** event delegation for dynamic elements. Also, sentences start with capital letters and "you" and "are" really aren't long words - don't be lazy, type them out, it makes a much better impression.